# Does std::next check if we are already at the end of the container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Suppose I have an iterator `std::list::iterator it = mylist.begin()` of a container, and I call

```
iterator it2 = std::next(it,1);
```

Does `std::next` check if `it == mylist.end()`?

Comment: you means to say  it != mylist.end() .no it doesn't check

Comment: The behavior is undefined if the specified sequence of increments or decrements would require that a non-incrementable iterator (such as the past-the-end iterator) is incremented, or that a non-decrementable iterator (such as the front iterator or the singular iterator) is decremented.

Answer (score 1):

No, the program was blocking in that situation. You should check yourself:

```
if (it != mylist.end())
    it2 = std::next(it,1);
```